# Nodejs Module loader will not export default from other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, require

I'm testing a backend framework that I'm building, and need a version that works with commonjs (`require`) and es6 modules (`import/export`). Currently I just have two source files, one that uses `import/export` and one that uses `require()`. The main file tests if require is defined, and if so exports the the commonjs version. If it is not defined, it exports the es6 version.

```
if(require)
    module.exports = require('./src/index.js')
else
    export {default} from './src/index.module.js'
```

I set `"type":"module"` in package.json, however node gets mad at me for that export:

```
(node:17992) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///C:/dev/JS/Node/Discord%20Bot%20Framework/index.js:4
    export {default} from './src/index.module.js'
    ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: https://zellwk.com/blog/publishing-npm-packages-that-can-be-used-in-browsers-and-node/#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20include,anytime%20after%20you%20link%20it.&text=This%20works%20because%20JavaScript%20in,JavaScript%20files%20you%20link%20to.

Comment: Check out the above article and this git repo - https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/returnExports.js